# Django's Form inside jQuery Dialog

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

i have site with main template (call it base.html), and some additional subpages rendered by separated views. In base.html i have menu, and clicking on one of the options display me a jquery dialog. I want to put a djangos form inside this dialog. I also want, that this dialog can send data regardless of what view is loaded. I think that i should use some decorator that will revive data from form, and this decorator should contains some ajax depend code?

---

I will clarify my problem.

I have a base.html template, that contains jQuery dialog window, and i want put there a django form. I also have template1.html, template2.html and so on that are rendered by view1, view2 respectively. template1.html, template2.html extends base.html. So i must put form handling code in every view that render template that inherit base.html. I would like to avoid that.

Comment: Umm, and what's your problem?

Comment: I will clarify my problem.

I have a base.html template, that contains jQuery dialog window, and i want put there a django form. I also have template1.html, template2.html and so on that are rendered by view1, view2 respectively. template1.html, template2.html extends base.html. So i must put form handling code in every view that render template that inherit base.html. I would like to avoid that.

Comment: So, I guess that you use one form class in each view, right? Where is problem, again? In each view you just call form's handler function, like so: `form = process_form(request.POST)`

Answer (score 0):

Just use template's inheritance, something like that:

```
# base.html
...
<div id="dialog">
 {% block dialog %}
   {% form_for_base.as_table %}
 {% endblock %}
</div>
...
```

And override `dialog` block in another template:

```
# template.html
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block dialog %}
  {% form_for_template.as_table %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Yes, but how to handle this in a view? In fact because this dialog can appear in many different subsites i must handle this in every view. So how to do it in an easy way.

Comment: Almost each view renders a template, right? So, where is problem?